# Any better way to make notifications

Tags: android, notifications

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(

                    context).setContentTitle("Recording...")

                    .setContentText("Currently recording")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            notificationManager.notify(9999, builder.build());
```

Edited code, 2 problems, PendingIntent and NotificationManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, RecordActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("Title of notification")
            .setContentText("Content title")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

notificationManager.notify(9999, builder.build());
```

And to cancel a notification:

```
notificationManager.cancel(9999);
```

Comment: See edited code, I got two problems - 1 - pendingIntent cannot be resolved to a variable - 2 -notificationManager cannot be resolved

Comment: Conserve you source code to create a PendingIntent and NotificationManager instances.